# Conditional expectation $E(X\mid XY)$ when $(X,Y)$ is standard normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

I have to calculate 
$\mathbb{E}(X|X*Y)$ with X,Y being independent and standard normal distributed. I got at tip in this post ([Conditional expectation on components of gaussian vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514721/conditional-expectation-on-components-of-gaussian-vector)), that I should use the definition and Bayes Thm to solve the problem. I played around a bit, but I just don't get it :(

May anyone give me another hint?

Comment: Have you made use of the information that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As every conditional expectation, $E[X\mid XY]=w(XY)$ for some measurable function $w$. Recall that:

> Conditional expectations depend only on the joint distribution of the random variables considered, in the sense that, if $E[X\mid XY]=w(XY)$, then $E[X'\mid X'Y']=w(X'Y')$ for every $(X',Y')$ distributed like $(X,Y)$.

Choosing $(X',Y')=(-X,-Y)$ above, one gets $X'Y'=XY$ hence $$w(XY)=E[-X\mid XY]=-E[X\mid XY]=-w(XY).$$ Thus, $$E[X\mid XY]=0.
$$
One sees that $E[X\mid XY]=0$ for every *centered* gaussian vector $(X,Y)$, neither necessarily independent nor standard.

Still more generally:

> Let $\Xi$ denote any centered gaussian vector, $u$ an *odd* measurable function such that $u(\Xi)$ is integrable and $v$ an *even* measurable function. Then, $$E[u(\Xi)\mid v(\Xi)]=0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Did, that clearly answeres my question! Although this technique may not apply to a problem like e.g. $\mathbb{E}(Z|XY)$ if $(X,Y,Z)$ is gaussian.
Btw, what is an "even" measurable function?

Comment: If `(X,Y,Z)` is centered, the argument works. "Even": `u(-x)=u(x)`. "Odd": `u(-x)=-u(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You know that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid XY=\alpha\right) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\beta f_{X\mid XY}\left(\beta\mid\alpha\right)d\alpha
$$
Now, using Bayes theorem
$$
f_{X\mid XY}\left(\beta\mid\alpha\right) = \frac{f_{XY\mid X}(\alpha\mid\beta)f_X(\beta)}{f_{XY}(\alpha)}.
$$

---

**THIS FOLLOWING IS NOT TRUE**

But,
$$
f_{XY\mid X}(\alpha\mid\beta) = f_Y\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right).
$$
and you can find the distribution of the product $XY$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249849/regular-version-of-conditional-gaussian-distribution).

---

All you need to do now is to substitute the last results in $f_{X\mid XY}$, and calculate the integral. I'm not sure whether there is a simple closed form result to this integral.

Comment: "But, fXY∣X(α∣β)=fY(αβ)". Sorry but this is not so.

Comment: and indeed I think that the distribution of XY is not given in the linked topic. I don't even think it is easy to calculate, right?

Answer (score -1):

you need to compute the integral : 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x f_{x|xy}) dx $$
where $f_{x|xy}$ is the conditional pdf. To find this pdf, $$f_{x|xy} = \frac{f_{x,xy}}{f_{xy}}$$ 
Try to do a transformation with $U=XY$ and $V=.....$ that can help you to compute the expectation